# Why do I get an "OpenGL Warning" message after running Google Chrome through the Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: 3d, opengl

I just downloaded Google Chrome for Ubuntu 64-bit onto my Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit OS (which is running as a guest as a VM on a Win 7 host). After it had installed, I opened up the terminal and typed "google chrome" and the web browser opened for the first time. Immediately below that line in the terminal, however, this appeared:

"OpenGL Warning: Failed to connect to host. Make sure 3D acceleration is enabled for this VM."

This message appeared 2 more times in the terminal before the cursor returned to normal. I am pretty sure I have 3D acceleration enabled, so what is causing this error message?

Comment: Please pastebin the output of `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`. An easy way to do that is `sudo apt-get install pastebinit`, and then `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p | pastebinit` -- just copy and paste the output URL then.

Comment: Got it; here it is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1040404/

Comment: What is your kernel name - `uname -r`? Please also pastebin the output of `lsmod`. The unity_support_test shows that Ubuntu can detect no 3D acceleration and is using the software llvmpipe renderer.

Comment: "uname -r" outputs the following: 
3.2.0-25-generic;                                  

For "lsmod": http://paste.ubuntu.com/1040414/

Comment: Can you confirm that you followed the instructions [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=15679) when installing guest additions?

Comment: No, I don't think I followed those instructions, and I can't for the time being because it says I don't have permission (I'm not logged in as root, but I can check on how to do this). When I installed guest additions, I just went to "Devices" and "Install Guest Additions." 

Also, for what it's worth, I accidentally downloaded the 32-bit version of Google Chrome for Ubuntu first, and then when I tried to install it, it proceeded with installing but at the end gave me a "package" error and asked if I wanted to "repair" the package, to which I clicked yes, but Chrome was not installed.

Comment: (C'tnd) I realized that I had downloaded the wrong version, so I downloaded the 64 bit one, and Chrome works fine, but it gives me that "OpenGL" error when I run it through the terminal. Also, strangely, Chrome does not show up in my "Ubuntu Software Manager", but it definitely works and is on my Ubuntu system. 

I will proceed with the instructions in the link you provided as soon as I log in as root, but I am a bit wary because that discussion is from 2009, so I am wondering if my current 12.04 version of Ubuntu will conflict with some of the commands/actions listed in that forum.

Comment: **Please use `sudo`** - not login as root. I haven't looked at the instructions in detail, but will tomorrow. Chrome isn't in the software center because it's not "free software" according to the Debian/Ubuntu policy. The highly recommended alternative is to install **Chromium**, which is the same as Chrome but stripped of the Google logos, trademarks, etc.

Comment: 10-4. I will do more research on this and on the instructions in the forum you provided; it's not a major issue since Ubuntu and Chrome are running fine, but I want to make sure I learn everything important regarding Ubuntu, error messages being a top priority- thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is from VirtualBox host additions. It means that the VM is unable to connect to the Host Virtual Card, and 3D acceleration, for the guest, can't work. It should appear every-time that something tries to access the 3D engine. For example, type:

```
glxinfo
```

The same error should appear. Usually, but not always, the cause is a permission problem.

Comment: I think it may in fact be a permission problem because when I was poking around my Ubuntu files (since I am trying to get acquainted with the Ubuntu environment), I was denied access to a file called "root", which I guess is the file that holds the "kernel" and other such fundamental system files?

Comment: Oh and I do not have "glxinfo" installed on my Ubuntu system at the moment.

Comment: `/root` is root's (Administrator's) home directory.